# Modify BigCommerce coupon error message

Tags: bigcommerce

I have an issue with BigCommerce where if someone tries to use a single-use coupon code for a second time, instead of saying that they already used it the error message states that "The coupon has expired...", I'm struggling to determine where to modify the error message and a method to determine if they had already used it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Design > More > Design Mode, and open your store in design mode, you will be able to change the variables that produce those strings to a new string. This will have a global effect on all coupon error messages as you are seeing now.

Alternatively, you can use javascript to target the text and alter it.

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately a js solution is undesirable, I'd rather modify the static content of the variable. I have several issues right now (not just error messages) where the cleanest solution is going to be modifying the actual variable's content, such as adding a list element to a dynamic list in example. I didn't see the design mode option, but that seems identical to just replacing the dynamic variable with static html which is also not what I'd want to do.